# How to use microsoft fakes to Mock HttpSessionStateBase

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mocking, moq, httpcontext

Moq Code:

```
mockControllerContext.SetupGet(x => x.HttpContext.Session["User"]).Returns(new User
{
    Name = "Moto", 
    IsAdmin = true                                                                                        
});
taskController.ControllerContext = mockControllerContext.Object;
```

How can i use MS Fakes to Mock HttpContext.Session???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [shims](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549176.aspx) for that with Microsoft Fakes.  However, I find this to be a bad practice.  Instead you should isolate yourself from third party libraries by wrapping them in your own class.  Then you can put an interface on that class and use your interface throughout your code.  This [anti-corruption layer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AnticorruptionLayer) allows you to shield yourself from third party assemblies and you are less affected when the third party assembly changes.

If you want to learn more about using shims, you can checkout [this Pluralsight course](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=microsoft-fakes) I authored on Microsoft Fakes.  (Full disclosure:  I get royalties on this course, but it is a quick way to get up to speed)

Answer (score 1):

Got these two functions from [here](http://www.emadibrahim.com/2008/04/04/unit-test-linq-to-sql-in-aspnet-mvc-with-moq/) in a class;

```
public static class HttpContextFactory
{
    public static void SetFakeAuthenticatedControllerContext(this Controller controller)
    {
        var httpContext = FakeAuthenticatedHttpContext();
        ControllerContext context =
        new ControllerContext(
          new RequestContext(httpContext,
          new RouteData()), controller);
        controller.ControllerContext = context;
    }
    private static HttpContextBase FakeAuthenticatedHttpContext()
    {
        var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
        var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
        var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
        var user = new Mock<IPrincipal>();
        var identity = new Mock<IIdentity>();
        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Request).Returns(request.Object);
        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Response).Returns(response.Object);
        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Session).Returns(session.Object);
        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Server).Returns(server.Object);
        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.User).Returns(user.Object);
        user.Setup(ctx => ctx.Identity).Returns(identity.Object);
        identity.Setup(id => id.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);
        identity.Setup(id => id.Name).Returns("a.ali174");
        return context.Object;
    }
}
```

From the unit test I called them as such;

```
 HttpContextFactory.SetFakeAuthenticatedControllerContext(controller);
```

Comment: I want to use MicroSoft Fakes FrameWork(VS2012) to Mock HttpSessionStateBasem,not use Moq.